# 1600 students form 16000 clubs with 80 members each. Prove that there are two clubs with at least four students in common.

Tags: combinatorics

I've tried a few things. Assuming there are 20 disjoint clubs containing every student in their union, then this is clearly true, because producing any more clubs would require at least 4 students from one of these clubs.

Otherwise, we can consider each club as being created by sampling a certain amount of students from each group. But I can't really get a bound on the maximum number of clubs we can create without exceeding the overlap criteria.

Comment: If there are $16000$ clubs with $80$ members each, then wouldn't there need to be $16000 \times 80 = 1280000$ students? Is there a typo in the problem statement?

Comment: students can be in more than one club.